# Unhandled error while running jest-puppeteer test

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I am trying to set up testing for my puppeteer project. I was following a basic guide and the test passes but there is 2 console errors in the terminal.

**The error doesn't show up when using https://google.com or https://youtube.com**. So it looks like it could be a thing with the specific site?

```
 console.error
    Unhandled error

      at process.uncaught (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:248:21)
      at handler (node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/lib/PuppeteerEnvironment.js:17:11)
      at map (node_modules/mitt/src/index.ts:74:75)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Object.emit (node_modules/mitt/src/index.ts:74:56)
      at Page.emit (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/EventEmitter.js:72:22)

  console.error

      at process.uncaught (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:249:21)
      at handler (node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/lib/PuppeteerEnvironment.js:17:11)
      at map (node_modules/mitt/src/index.ts:74:75)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Object.emit (node_modules/mitt/src/index.ts:74:56)
      at Page.emit (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/EventEmitter.js:72:22)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.613 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Here is my code

```
describe('NCAA Home', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      await page.goto('http://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div');
    });
  
    it('should be titled "NCAA Statistics"', async () => {
      await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('NCAA Statistics');
    });
});
```

Here is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-puppeteer",
    testMatch: [
      "**/test/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    verbose: true
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-puppeteer"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

All of the things I have come across have mentioned an issue with async/await but anything I have tried produces the same, if not, more errors. I have made a new project with these files and I am getting the same error

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The code you posted isn't supposed to cause these errors because promise rejections are handled, so it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the website itself. Check the console of the website. Hence for a websites like google.com or youtube.com, it works without any errors.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to either resolve this in the terminal or at least hide it?

Comment: Not sure sorry, I think you could try to mock the console.error function and not show it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created clean repo which reproduces issue.
https://github.com/sergtimosh/jest-puppeteer-issue-reproduction.git

- clone repository
- npm i
- npm test test.spec.js

or

- HEADLESS=false npm test test.spec.js

A workaround is to create incognito browser context in **`jest-environment.js`**.
Just uncomment two lines in this file and tests are passing with no issues. But problem is still here if you need to share browser context between test suites(files).

```js
const PuppeteerEnvironment = require('jest-environment-puppeteer');


class JestEnvironment extends PuppeteerEnvironment {

  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    //to fix issue uncomment next two lines
    // const incognitoContext = await this.global.browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()
    // this.global.page = await incognitoContext.newPage()

  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown()
  }

}

module.exports = JestEnvironment;
```